# return a value from a button menu choice

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I surrender, I’m raising the white flag and getting down on my knees and begging for help. The problem that has driven me to this is as follows.

I need to write a method that calls a sub method which returns a char value.
The sub menu needs to be GUI interface. 
But it cannot be a dialog box.
The main method needs to then use this information for calling the required methods.

Can anyone help me with this one? Simple code example would help.

Comment: why can't it be a dialog box?

Comment: Are you planning to use Swing for this? And post what you have tried so far. Also if this is homework please tag it as such.

Comment: `JMenuItem`? `JTextField`? the question is a little vague can you clarify?  May be with an example??

Comment: If all you want is for the user to be able to choose between two different options, some kind of dialog seems like it's the best idea. For easy construction of predefined dialogs, have a look at the JOptionPane class. E.g. [the showOptionDialog method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you're looking for, I'm guessing you could find it pretty quickly in the Swing section of StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing

There are many [sscce](http://sscce.org/) in both questions and answers which will give you a starting point for creating a GUI (which I assume is your sticking point at the moment).

With that assumption, here's some code to get you started - this will create a frame and a content panel for you.  Other components will tend to extend the [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) object (like [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html), [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html), and [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)).  The [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html) are a great item to browse (easiest in "frames" mode) for more information on Java and Swing.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainPanel extends Box{

    public MainPanel(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        // Add other elements to your box using:
        // add(item to add);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new MainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```